# Level set of Hamiltonian are the orbits?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, complex-systems, integrable-systems

Just a small question : If $x(t)=(p(t),q(t))$, then the position $x(t)$ of a particle is given by $$\dot p=-H_q(x(t))\quad \text{and}\quad \dot q=H_p(x(t)).$$
In particular, if $x$ solve the previous system, then $\frac{d}{dt}H(x(t))=0,$ i.e. $H(x(t))$ is constant for all $t$. Does it mean that the orbits are exactly the level set of the Hamiltonian? Or there are level sets that are not orbits?

Answer (score 5):

The orbits are level sets but not all level sets are in the same orbit.  Imagine a double-well potential: it’s easy to see one can have disjoint orbits of the same energy, one each in a distinct well.

Comment: Another example is a free particle in 1-D, where orbits with $E \neq 0$ consist of two lines of constant $p = \pm \sqrt{2E/m}$ in phase space, and the orbits with $E = 0$ consist of single points.